# Multiple Group Managers in Organic Group

Tags: organic-groups

The "Owner / Group Manager" of a group appears to be the person that created the container (let's say a node). That, of course, is controlled by the UID of that node.

Is it possible to have multiple "Group Managers". If that is possible, it would seem to mandate something else controlling the status of "Group Manager".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so intuition told me that this was a can do... Really, membership and controlling the permissions of members is largely what OG is about.

Anyway, the brief solution that I was looking for is this:

1. Edit the node containing the group in question from group manager account
2. Click Group Tab
3. Click Add people
4. Add user name
5. Go back to /admin/people (this is where the magic happens)
6. Check the box beside the username in update options.
7. open dropdown box
8. Select **Administrator member** click Update

Voilà!

There is much more that can be done (for example adding custom roles). Explore on!

Comment: How does this make that user a group manager? You've just made him site-wide admin, not group manager.

Comment: Good question by turion! You are just making the user as a admin user, thus all the OG permissions are overridden. This is not the exact way to have multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be only one Group Owner / Group Manager for a group, because there is only one author for a node.

When you change the author of that group, you will change the owner / manager of that group either.

BUT, if you only concern about the permissions, you can just grant the "Administer group" permission for the group role, then users of that group role will have the same ability as the group manager has, e.g. delete the group. And if you are looking for the opposite, revoke "Administer group".